# How To add new webapi project using powershell with specified version

Tags: powershell, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

when I used this command in powershell 
`dotnet new webapi -n NewCatalog` 
it creat a webapi project base on default version in my pc 2.2  
I install .netcore 5 and try to use this command  
`dotnet new webapi -n NewCatalog --sdk-version 5.0.15 --force` 
But I fail 
**Invalid input switch:**
**--sdk-version**
**5.0.15**
So
How To add new webapi project using powershell with specified version

Answer (score 0):

This command below can work for you to create a project with a specific .NET version.

```
 dotnet new webapi -f net5.0 -n NewCatalog
```

Comment: thanks a lot the main problem with me that i must install Both<br/>
.NET 5.0  SDK<br/>
.NET 5.0 Runtime<br/>
and after that i must update visual studio 2019 <br/>
after that I think  all  will work<br/>